# Export a model containing only edges

Tags: modeling, export, import, edges, unity

I'm wondering if there's a way to export a model containing only edges.

I modeled the Blender camera, but I cannot import it into Unity. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I don't think any of the available exchange file formats  even supports that at all. Why not fill the faces and just export a regular model? What are you trying to achieve? It's unlikely Unity is going to be able to deal with a wire model anyway.

Comment: dae exports it by default, and fbx and gltf export it if you turn on the "Loose Edges" option. Don't know what unity will do with it though.