# How to export a circle shape from blender to unity3d?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, unity

using Blender 4.0

This is how I created the circle:

pressed on Shift + A keys in the opened menu selected Mesh > Circle.

to move the circle up only one axis only up I first selecting the circle by just clicking on the circle then pressed on G after that pressing the axis, I want it to move on so in this case Z then just moving the mouse up down and to keep the circle in that position click on the mouse left button.

now while the circle is selected, I pressed the TAB key to enter the edit mode and it's showing me all the vertices of the circle.

[image: circle all vertices selected]

now to add more vertices I clicked on the mouse right button and in the opened menu I selected Subdivide few times to add as many as I need more vertices to the circle.

[image: circle with more vertices]

next I did is pressed the A key to select all vertices then pressed W key and in the opened menu clicked on Subdivide many times.

now I want to export it and use in unity3d:

I clicked in the menu on Mesh > Notrmals > Recalculate Outside

what it does is open a window in the bottom name > Recalculate Normal if I expand the arrow there is a checkbox inside say Inside.

that's it.

then in the menu I did:  File > Export > FBX (.fbx) gave it a name and export it.

I dragged the new created file to my unity3d editor and then to the hierarchy but no circle and in most of the cases I'm getting warning:

Can't calculate tangents, because mesh 'Circle' doesn't contain normals.
and in some cases that it didn't show the warning still it didn't show the circle.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. There are no faces in your model. You cannot export only vertices and edges. There have to be faces as far as I know.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277586/export-a-model-containing-only-edges

Answer (score 0):

If you create the circle this way, it will not have any faces. I don't think Unity will render edges by default. You need to add polygons.

After adding the circle, press <kbd>F9</kbd> to adjust the operator settings, and set the *Fill Type* to Triangle Fan. You can optionally increase the number of Vertices here instead of subdividing the circle afterwards.

[image: Circle]

The tangents warning has nothing to do with the circle not showing up. I think you need custom normals for that which can be added in different ways. The easiest is to run *Mesh > Normals > Reset Vectors* or *Mesh > Normals > Smooth Vectors* in Edit Mode with everything selected.

Comment: there is no reset normals in edit mode.  I did Mesh > Normals but no reset normals.  and no matter how many times I make Mesh > Normals >  recalculate outside in unity it keep showing that there is no normals.  Can't calculate tangents, because mesh 'Circle' doesn't contain normals.

Comment: @Jack Sorry, that was a typo. I meant `Reset Vectors`. I will fix it in my answer. Try that or `Smooth Vectors`, and check if it makes a difference.